# Error with % and & despite using verb option

Tags: listings, verbatim, tabularray

I am new to tabularray and I have a problem typesetting tables with code in it.

I see the option `verb` must be given to environment `tblr` to allow verbatim text, but even then, characters `%` and `&` cause an error :

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{verb,colspec={c}}
\verb!%!
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

gives `\verb ended by end of line. \end`. The same happens with `&`.

I am at a loss because giving `\%` or `\&` prints out the backslash as well.

I am compiling with lualatex if that matters.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Could be reported here: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/new.

Comment: Another workaround: use `fancyvrb`'s `\SaveVerb{<name>}!verb!` before `tabularray` and then `\UseVerb{<name>}` inside it.

Comment: Reported in https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/358

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
It Seems that you find a bug in option `verb`. In this can help you (us) the package author ...

However meantime you can use  `\texttt` command instead of `\verb˙`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\verb!%!

\begin{tblr}{colspec={c}}
\texttt{\%}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code you typed works by me as well. But it produces ``\%`` in the output, and I want ``%``.

Comment: Ah, i overlooked this. It seems that you find a bug in tabularray, so wee need help of package author. Until this see edited answer, if this can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can temporarily change the category of the comment with `\catcode`%=12`. A disadvantage: in the source code it always appears as a comment
2. Create a command to change `&` to `\&` and use `\texttt`

**The code**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myverb}{m}{
        \char_set_catcode_other:N \&
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
        \regex_replace_all:nnN { & } { \& } \l_tmpa_tl 
        \texttt{\l_tmpa_tl}
        \char_set_catcode_alignment:N \&
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\verb|%abcd&|

\catcode`\%=12
\myverb{%abcd&}
\catcode`\%=14 

\catcode`\%=12
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={c c},
    vlines}
    \myverb{%abcd&}     & Another word\\
    azerty&\myverb{%a%b&cd}
\end{tblr}
\catcode`\%=14
% comment
\end{document}
```

[image]